# Watch external content in real time in node.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, node.js, redis

Is there any way to to watch external files and when the content changes, fire some event?

For example, I have external API, and I want to watch it. When API response content changes, immediately fire some event.

Another example - I am doing a HTTP GET/POST request to the API server. API returns JSON with some data - e.g. `{"song": "some song name", "timestamp": "123121212"}`. This API returns song, what's currently playing in radio. API response content is updated, when another song starts to play.

Right now I am updating song using shell and PHP - I am making request to API server every 10 seconds, and if there are any changes (I am logging response to database), PHP updates it on database and with socket.io (and Redis) shows it to client.

I don't want to make request every 10 seconds, so is there any way, to watch external file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, if the remote API does not offer any mechanism for you to be notified of some changes (e.g. by calling an URL that you control), then polling is your only option.

Maybe in your case you could get the duration of the current song, the current position in this song and wait for the end of the song to make a new request? For instance if you know that *Never gonna give you up* (duration 3:32) is playing and is currently at 2:32, you could schedule your next API call to be made in approximately 1 minute.